# Jaws 17 and startup keyboard shortcut

Tags: jaws-screen-reader

I've a friend who need use a screen reader. He uses Jaws 17 and Jaws 16.
He puts a startup shortcut Ctrl+Alt+K for Jaws 16 (I don't see it on shortcut on the desktop... don't know where he does it) And He puts Ctrl + Alt + J for Jaws 17. This I can see it on property of shortcut. 
Ctrl+Alt+K run very goog but not Ctrl+Alt+J. I try tu put another letter, W or Z, but same problem. You can double click on shortCut, Jaws 17 start, but not with shortcut keyboard.
Someone have an idea, what difference between double click and uses shortcut keybord?

I forget. I'm in Windows 10. When I install Jaws 17, shortcut run, but after pass update Jaws 17.0.1377 shortcut don't run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was the keyboard... But don't know why? I see other problems after, I need to press very strong on some touch (E, L...). Then to solve this problem I change keyboard and just to try the first problem it's good after...
But I'm not convinced... But it's ok now...